# Check if an Active Directory is ready

Tags: c#, dns, controller, active-directory

I'm trying to check if a domain controller is ready to receive requests. A simple ping is not enough since, for example after a reboot, the network comes back in a few seconds but it takes several minutes for the domain controller to be ready and clients to be able to open a session.

I found this simple code:

```
public bool IsDomainControllerAvailable(string domainControllerName)
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryContext context = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, domainControllerName);

        DomainController domainController = DomainController.FindOne(context);

        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I think this function is great, but I have two questions.

- Is this the right way to ensure that a domain controller is ready to receive requests?
- Is repeating this check every second to have a constant monitor a problem?

Comment: You may want to look at the [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/tour) sites and read up on whether either of them would be appropriate for a rephrased version of this question (about checking with such a high frequency).  Also note that there is a [`domaincontroller`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/domaincontroller) tag.  I'd recommend swapping out `controller` for that.

Comment: Usually, there are multiple domain controllers. Are you really looking for a specific domain controller to be ready, or do you just need to know if Active Directory is ready?

Comment: @TawabWakil I just need to know if an Active Directory is ready, no matter wich domain controller answer the request.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't care which domain controller answers the request, I would suggest something like this:

```
public bool IsActiveDirectoryAvailable()
{
    try
    {
        string adDomainName = Domain.GetComputerDomain().Name;
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(adDomainName);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This returns true only if it is able to connect to the Active Directory (AD) domain and get the domain name.

As far as how often to call this, it depends on your requirements. I don't think once a second would cause a problem, but I would test it. Call it too often and it may hurt performance. Call it too little and it may take too long for it to tell you AD is ready. If you're not sure, I'd suggest every 5 or 10 seconds as a reasonable starting point. Then you can experiment with different values to find what works for you.